# Codeigniter queries colliding

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have something really weird happening.

It looks like I have 2 active record queries colliding and mixing up tablenames and where statements.

I am using Codeigniter and I am trying to have session stored in the database. I want to be able to retrieve the user info from that session.

I've extended my controllers to store userdata and sessionId in a variable I can use anywhere:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public $User = false;
    public $UserLoopCount = 0;
    public $SessionId = false;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->SessionId = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        $this->User = $this->user_model->user($this->SessionId);

    }

}
```

All of my database tables have a field called "AccountId" which say which user account the data belongs to.

In all my user database queries I am applying the following function:

```
public function accountLock($alias=false) {
    $user = $this->user_model->user();
    echo $this->User;
    if($user) {
        $alias === false ? $this->db->where("AccountId =", "{$user->AccountId}") : $this->db->where("{$alias}.AccountId =", "{$user->AccountId}");          
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which ensures the "where AccountID = $AccountId" is always added to the users queries.

This function:

```
$user = $this->user_model->user();
```

Is supposed to get the userdata from the database so I can access the AccountId in the where statement of a query such as get records for the user to see.

It used to do this:

```
return array_shift($this->session->userdata('user_data');
```

So for database I switched it to this:

```
return $user = $this->get_user_by_session_id($sessionId)->user_data;
```

And this is where things are starting to get weird. If I load pages normally via URL everything works fine. As soon as I do it via Ajax, I am getting queries collide.

The where statement from this query ends up in the original query that needed to grab the user data, it is also affecting the JOINs from that query by mixing tablenames:

```
public function get_user_by_session_id($sessionId) {

    $this->db->start_cache();
    $this->db->where("session_id =", $sessionId); // THIS WHERE STATEMENT ENDS UP IN ORIGINAL QUERY THAT CALLED TO GET THE USER INFO
    $query = $this->db->get("active_users");
    $this->db->stop_cache();
    $this->db->flush_cache();

    echo $this->db->last_query();

    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->row() : false;

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why not just turn on the native database engine for session storage in a database? its built right into codeigniter, no reason to write your own...

Comment: I did, that is what caused the problem. Now when I get the user data from the database it's running a query in the middle of other queries so I can apply my where AccountId = $thisUser->AccountId clause